# Firebase functions can't access my middleware routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
///index.js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const productRouter = require('./routes/productRoutes');
const globalErrorHandler = require('./controllers/errorController');
const AppError = require('./utils/appError');

// Compressing upcompressed files which is been sent to client such text.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World')
});

app.get('/homepage', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello People of God')
});

app.use('/products', productRouter);

// Handing Unhandled Routes
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
    next(new AppError(`Can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`, 404));
});

app.use(globalErrorHandler);
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);



///productRoutes.js
const express = require('express');
const {
    getProduct,
    getAllProduct,
} = require('./../controllers/productController');
const router = express.Router();
router
    .route('/')
    .get(getAllProduct);

router
    .route('/:id')
    .get(getProduct);

module.exports = router;



///productController.js
const AppError = require('../utils/appError');
const Product = require('../modals/productModels');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');

// GET SINGLE PRODUCT CONTROLLER
exports.getProduct = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id)
        .populate('reviews');

    if (!product) {
        return next(new AppError('No product found with that ID', 404));
    }

    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        data: {
            product
        }
    });
});

// GET ALL PRODUCT CONTROLLER
exports.getAllProduct = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const products = await Product.find();

    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        results: products.length,
        data: {
            products
        }
    });
});



///server.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = require('./index')
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// CONNECTING TO MONGODB SERVER
dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' })
const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace('<PASSWORD>', process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD);

mongoose.connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    safe: true,
    strict: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(con => console.log('DB connection successful'))

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

After running function serve on my terminal i can access the two '/' and 'homepage' app.get which return the res "Hello world" and "Hello people of God" but can't access app.use('/products', productRouter). Its does take some time to run and throw an error "{"code":"ECONNRESET"}" please why is this so.

Am expecting to get my list of products from my mongodb data base.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add code of `productRouter` file? It could be that you are not returning a response from any of the route?

Comment: @-Dharmaraj thanks for your response have done that kindly cross-check for me again.